# How to get K largest sum of combination made from inputted numbers

Tags: python, combinations

The input to my program is a list of numbers sorted in ascending order.

What I need as output is K-largest sum made of 3-number combinations from the list.

Since this may be little confusing, let me explain on my algorithm:

- My list consist of numbers 1 2 3 4, I need the K-largest sum
- Make all possible combinations as lists ([1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4])
- Make a list containing the sum of each combination ([6],[7],[8],[9])
- Sort list in descending order, and print the number in the Kth position

This is my program in python, but the problem is that it's spending time doing to many combinations. Sometimes I have list containing 3000 numbers and it takes too long to create all possible combinations.

Is there some way how to avoid doing all these combinations?

```
import itertools
k = input('Here goes the K').split()
array = [int(x) for x in input('Here goes list of numbers').split()]
k=int(k)
combs=[]  
result=[]

result=[sum(x) for x in itertools.combinations(array,3)] 
result.sort(reverse=True)  

print(result[k-1])
```

Comment: you call `int(k)`, but `k` is a list?

Comment: Hint: when is a number greater than another number? How can you obtain the *i*-th combination?

Comment: I guess the gist of the task is that you need to find an algorithm that produces the combinations in descending order of their sum. Then you never have to generate all, but only k.

Comment: I forgot to delete int(k) and .split() , i have written just part of a code, and originally it is list of two numbers, "n" and "k"..

Comment: Actually the problem is that even if i produce combinations in descending order of sums i can't stop at "k" sum bucause very likely there will be bigger sum after "k" is reached, i don't need smallest of K, but K-largest of all, and that's the problem

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic programming

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The program i did is exactly what i'm trying to do, I would only like it to be more efficient. I'm a high school student and the former quest was formed like: "john made 10 cards with numbers on them, then made all trinities and wrote sums of them on a paper. Make program which finds K-th largest sum in the list"  I did the program you can see there, which works great for 10 given numbers, but not so well for maybe 10^5 numbers. So I've been trying to find a another way but i'm clueless and so is my teacher @JaredGoguen

Comment: @detsales70, have you tried the solution provided below?

Comment: Are the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... and so on without gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my second-edited attempt with time complexity `O(nlogn + K)` and space complexity `O(n)`.

```
L = [9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1]
K = 3
L = sorted(L,reverse = True)
N = len(L)
i, j, l = 0, 1, 2

A = [c-v for c, v in zip(L[:-1], L[1:])]+[0]    

while(K-1>0):
    if(l < N-1 and (A[l] < A[j] or j==l-1) and (A[l] < A[i] or i==j-1) ):
       l+=1
    elif(j < N-2 and  (A[l] < A[i] or i==j-1) ):
       j+=1
    else:
       i+=1
    K-=1

print '{}\n{}\n{}'.format(L[i],L[j],L[l])
```

Haven't tested too much for corner cases but I think it's fine.

Example for

```
L = [9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1]
```

output:

```
9
7
6
```

---

**Explanation - Algorithm correctness**

The above algorithm starts with three pointers i,j,l pointing to the 1st,2nd and 3rd element of sorted list which is the combination with greatest sum.

Then computes the difference between `L[i+1],L[i]` for every i and then loops `K-1` times to find kth max sim combination. In each iteration in order to guarantee that we move the right pointer in order to achieve the next greater sum we move the pointer that can be moved (e.g is inside array index and doesn't overlap with next pointer) with least `L[i]`. After `K-1` iterations we find the kth max sum combination.

The steps for the example input is:

```
initially: 9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1
           ^  ^  ^
           |  |  |
           i  j  l    

step1:     9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1
           ^  ^     ^
           |  |     |

step2:     9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1 and not  9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1  which is non optimal  (and previous solution (before edit) choosed)
           ^     ^  ^                ^  ^        ^
           |     |  |                |  |        |
```

-

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Jared Goguen 's useful comments this algorithm has some issues described in comments and does not give always right result. I'll try to edit later today or delete it...

Comment: This runs into the same issue that my answer did. When iterating over [5, 4, 3, 1] for subsets of size 2, the first point should be moved over before the second pointer gets to the end.

Comment: The subsets will be only size 3, can you give an example (what is the K ) and why the  first point should be moved over before the second pointer gets to the end?

Comment: Use [9, 8, 7, 2, 1]. It seems like [9, 2, 1] would be generated before [8, 7, 2].

Comment: Or, if not, when using [9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1], would [8, 7, 6] be generated before [9, 8, 1]?

Comment: @JaredGoguen, edited answer in order to consider which pointer to move, e.g which movement is optimal, this has an overhead O(k) in comparison with previous attempt...

Comment: @coder this is working!! great job, thanks a lot, nice solution

Comment: It seems like this algorithm could only work for very small K. For example, if the state [0,1,4] is reached, it will then never reach the state [1,2,3], and vice-versa. The issue is that i, j, and k will need to be "reset" at some point and/or backtracking may be required. That's why a dynamic programming approach is needed for a general solution.

Comment: @JaredGoguen, Can you give an example list that would lead in failure, cause it is not very clear...

Comment: @JaredGoguen, also there is no small or big K if a bug occurs then there will be for small or big input... What exactly means [0,1,4] a list of pointers [i,j,k] and if needed to go to [1,2,3] then it would go before. If you read the correctness "proof" you will see that this is a greedy algorithm choosing the best option in each step, if you have a counter example please provide it..

Comment: Your algorithm can't step through all of the possible combinations in a single go. For example, does it produce [6, 2, 1] for K=20?

Comment: Hint: it will error out because it can only iterate through 9 combinations, not all 20.

Comment: That's a valid point ,you're saying if run out of combinations need backtracking?? (if yes than I agree I'll check if could fix it, though a dynamic programming algorithm with a quick look seems to take O(n^2K ) which is not much better O(n^3) initially...)

Comment: You'll need to backtrack long before you run out of combinations. When given a pool of six values, this algorithm will produce the minimum combination as the 9th combination, and never even look at 11 other combinations that are greater than it.

Comment: I got an incorrect answer when using this algorithm for the following inputs:

`L = [9, 8, 6, 2, 1]` and `K = 4`. I got `9 6 1` but expected `9 6 2` to be printed.

Comment: @richizy, see the edit in my answer, I have acknowledged (long time ago) that it does not guarantee always optimal result unfortunately